# Chrome refuses to load .aspx page

Tags: .net, google-chrome, iis, http-status-code-404

I´m using IIS7 and WS2012. My asp.net application is 3.5

My site opens good on IE and FF but when try to use Google Chrome a 404 error appears.

I already tried to register aspnet again many times.

Regards

Comment: Have you checked the `App_Start` folder in the `RouteConfig.cs` file in Visual Studio? Maybe your default routing is mis-configured. Do you have an `Index` action in your `HomeController`?

Comment: Hi, i´m not using routes. When I open a .html file opens normal. The problem is only with .aspx files and just in Google Chrome.